# Загрузить файл больших размеров на сервер

Tags: php

В `nas DNS - 320` установил  `lighttpd` и `php`, закинул скрипт `veno file manager 1.6.8`.
Проблема с загрузкой файлов больших размеров. В файле php.ini прописал следующие настройки

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 1280M 
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
post_max_size = 5000M
```

При загрузке максимум позволяет загружать 2 Гб.
Тестировал скрипт на локалке openserver, там без проблем загружается.

При понижение в файле php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Сервер ограничивает загрузку (загружаю 1,5 Гб, а загружается 940 MB).

Пробовал ставить в файле максимальные значения - не помогло, куда копать не знаю.

Comment: увеличьте memory_limit и лимиты времени.

Comment: смысл прописывать `upload_max` больше чем `post_max` ? Если объем загружаемого файла оказывается больше, чем можно залить, то у вас вообще не зальется ничего. Проверьте настройки самого файл-менеджера этого, он ведь может менять их через `ini_set`. убедитесь, что `max_execution_time` 180сек достаточно для загрузки 2гигабайт. И то что на жестком диске в разделе куда заливается временный файл достаточно места.

Comment: Это вы поправили настройки самого php, а что с настройками самого вебсервера? У меня допустим, стоят nginx + httpd - нужно прописывать ещё и  в nginx лимиты, иначе до бекенда не дойдёт.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: server.max-request-size
maximum size in kbytes of the request (header + body).
Default: 2097152 (2GB)  может что сам web server lighttpd ограничивает  загрузку и файлы больше  2097152 нельзя загрузить ?